# JQuery package reference a main file that does not exist? Aurelia, CLI, Materialize-Bridge

Tags: command-line-interface, materialize, aurelia

I installed Materialize-Bridge following [this instructions](https://aurelia-ui-toolkits.gitbooks.io/materialize-bridge-docs/content/installation/aurelia-cli.html). When I run `au build` it says that it can not find `index.js`. Project did run successfully until I added Materialize Bridge.

I have two problems:

- don't know where can I edit path that searches for `index.js` file (current path is invalid -- my node_modules are located at `SOMETHING_ELSE/node_modules` and not at `SOMETHING_ELSE/src/node_modules`)
- can not locate `index.js` file for jquery (it is not in `node_modules/jquery`)

  ```
  Starting 'readProjectConfiguration'...
  Unable to analyze jquery
  [Error: The "jquery" package references a main file that does not exist: /PATH/TO/SOMETHING/SOMETHING_ELSE/src/node_modules/jquery/index.js]
  { uid: 1,
    name: 'readProjectConfiguration',
    branch: false,
    error: [Error: The "jquery" package references a main file that does not exist: /PATH/TO/SOMETHING/SOMETHING_ELSE/src/node_modules/jquery/index.js],
    duration: [ 0, 10966665 ],
    time: 1500372612034 }
  { uid: 0,
    name: '<series>',
    branch: true,
    error: [Error: The "jquery" package references a main file that does not exist: /PATH/TO/SOMETHING/SOMETHING_ELSE/src/node_modules/jquery/index.js],
    duration: [ 0, 23847781 ],
    time: 1500372612046 }
  [Error: The "jquery" package references a main file that does not exist: /PATH/TO/SOMETHING/SOMETHING_ELSE/src/node_modules/jquery/index.js]
  ```

  **Where can I change path to `index.js` file and where should that file be located?** I hope I was clear enough, if not please ask for more information. Thanks

Comment: This is strange. jQuery should not require an `index.js` configuration as its package.json config points to `dist/jquery.js`.. Actually, is jquery present in node_modules? What does jquery's `package.json` say for `main`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an issue in `aurelia.json`. `"path": "../node_modules/materialize-css/dist`" was not set correctly.